# Creating an AP with OpenWRT and RPi but cannot find the SSID

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, openwrt

I have a RPi on which I want to create a 'low user' captive portal. This works under Raspian, but as I need some network routing changes I am trying OpenWRT too. But I don't seem to be able to get a clean install to work as an AP.

I installed the required drivers and everything seems to work, but cannot find the SSID to be scannable by any of my devices. Is there something stupid I a missing?

LuCI gives:

```
Generic 802.11bgn Wireless Controller (radio0)  
Signal: 0 dBm / Noise: 0 dBm
0%  SSID: Tourguide
Mode: Master
Channel: 1 (2.412 GHz)
Bitrate: ? Mbit/s
BSSID: 00:0F:55:A2:43:84
Encryption: None
```

Ifconfig:

```
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:27:EB:FF:A3:3D  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:feff:a33d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1086 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:490 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:151856 (148.2 KiB)  TX bytes:154909 (151.2 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:27:EB:FF:A3:3D  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1512 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:483 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:234130 (228.6 KiB)  TX bytes:159395 (155.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1596 (1.5 KiB)  TX bytes:1596 (1.5 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:55:A2:43:84  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:55ff:fea2:4384/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:598 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:102488 (100.0 KiB)
```

(so it seems to sent something at least??)

root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/config/wireless

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option hwmode '11g'
    option path 'platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0'
    option txpower '20'
    option country 'IE'
    option channel 'auto'
    option htmode 'HT20'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'Tourguide'
    option encryption 'none'
    option network 'lan'
```

root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/config/network

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option type 'bridge'
    option _orig_ifname 'eth0'
    option _orig_bridge 'true'
    option proto 'dhcp'

config interface 'wan6'
    option ifname '@wan'
    option proto 'dhcpv6'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd02:649d:5a81::/48'
```

This is my start log:

```
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.026459] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.032531] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.238659] Core Release: 2.80a
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.241900] Setting default values for core params
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.246813] Finished setting default values for core params
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.452612] Using Buffer DMA mode
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.456011] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.461962] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.467659] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.472094] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.debug kernel: [    1.475820] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.475879] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: DWC OTG Controller
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.480936] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.488334] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: irq 32, io mem 0x00000000
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.493938] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.497956] Init: Power Port (0)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.501358] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.508300] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.515643] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.520458] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.10.49 dwc_otg_hcd
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.526297] usb usb1: SerialNumber: bcm2708_usb
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.531737] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.535603] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.debug kernel: [    1.540054] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.debug kernel: [    1.540071] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.debug kernel: [    1.540080] dwc_otg: FIQ split fix enabled
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.debug kernel: [    1.540101] Module dwc_common_port init
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.540479] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.551094] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.561062] bcm2708 watchdog, heartbeat=10 sec (nowayout=0)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.570667] cpuidle: using governor ladder
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.578814] cpuidle: using governor menu
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.586633] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.596845] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.605293] sdhci: Enable low-latency mode
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.657352] mmc0: SDHCI controller on BCM2708_Arasan [platform] using platform's DMA
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.669383] mmc0: BCM2708 SDHC host at 0x20300000 DMA 4 IRQ 20
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.679457] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.689962] TCP: cubic registered
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.697550] NET: Registered protocol family 17
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.notice kernel: [    1.706197] Bridge firewalling registered
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.714358] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.723019] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.738577] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.748207] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    1.937372] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    1.948262] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.158116] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.169279] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.182005] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.190368] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.477629] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    2.512653] mmc0: SD Status: Invalid Allocation Unit size.
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.523567] mmc0: new SD card at address cb78
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.532770] mmcblk0: mmc0:cb78 SD01G 982 MiB 
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.543469]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.warn kernel: [    2.579438] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.593425] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.604715] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.619416] smsc95xx v1.0.4
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.695886] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:ff:a3:3d
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.755734] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.767971] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.778930] Freeing unused kernel memory: 104K (c03b2000 - c03cc000)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.790344] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.931396] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=040b, idProduct=2000
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.943105] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.954927] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Keyboard
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    2.963726] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    3.067621] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    3.195648] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=5370
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    3.207152] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    3.219095] usb 1-1.3: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    3.228017] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Ralink
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    3.236518] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 1.0
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    7.531332] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    9.778628] NET: Registered protocol family 10
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    9.821037] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (7038 buckets, 28152 max)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    9.837174] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    9.861511] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    9.893587] Loading modules backported from Linux version master-2014-05-22-0-gf2032ea
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    9.906101] Backport generated by backports.git backports-20140320-37-g5c33da0
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    9.923004] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    9.961981] input: Generic USB Keyboard as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input0
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [    9.977860] hid-generic 0003:040B:2000.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Generic USB Keyboard] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input0
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.011831] input: Generic USB Keyboard as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/input/input1
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.049805] hid-generic 0003:040B:2000.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Generic USB Keyboard] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input1
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.067108] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.077690] usbhid: USB HID core driver
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.129623] xt_time: kernel timezone is -0000
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.155885] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.190617] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.200864] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.205359] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.224593] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.237597] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.250543] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.263418] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.276332] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.289208] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.302151] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.314970] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.374924] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.388804] NET: Registered protocol family 24
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.517596] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.638589] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.695888] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5370 detected
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.debug kernel: [   10.708692] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
Mon Jan 12 20:24:20 2015 kern.info kernel: [   10.710832] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb
Mon Jan 12 20:24:22 2015 authpriv.info dropbear[422]: Not backgrounding
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 user.emerg syslog: - init complete -
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 daemon.warn netifd: You have delegated IPv6-prefixes but haven't assigned them to any interface. Did you forget to set option ip6assign on your lan-interfaces?
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 kern.info kernel: [   16.474564] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 kern.info kernel: [   16.487272] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 kern.info kernel: [   16.501795] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 kern.info kernel: [   16.513802] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br-lan: link is not ready
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' is enabled
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'loopback' is enabled
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'loopback' is setting up now
Mon Jan 12 20:24:24 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'loopback' is now up
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'lo' link is up
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'loopback' has link connectivity 
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 kern.info kernel: [   17.052676] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: IE
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 kern.info kernel: [   17.085261] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: IE
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 kern.info kernel: [   17.096057] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 kern.info kernel: [   17.100492] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 kern.info kernel: [   17.119584] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 kern.info kernel: [   17.132433] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 kern.info kernel: [   17.145262] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 kern.info kernel: [   17.157918] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:25 2015 kern.info kernel: [   17.170695] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[572]: started, version 2.71 cachesize 150
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[572]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP no-DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack no-ipset no-auth no-DNSSEC
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[572]: using local addresses only for domain lan
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.warn dnsmasq[572]: no servers found in /tmp/resolv.conf.auto, will retry
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[572]: read /etc/hosts - 1 addresses
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 kern.info kernel: [   18.092150] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 kern.info kernel: [   18.123934] br-lan: port 1(eth0) entered forwarding state
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 kern.info kernel: [   18.134427] br-lan: port 1(eth0) entered forwarding state
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 kern.info kernel: [   18.144931] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'eth0' link is up
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Bridge 'br-lan' link is up
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' has link connectivity 
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' is setting up now
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 kern.info kernel: [   18.173112] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br-lan: link becomes ready
Mon Jan 12 20:24:26 2015 daemon.notice netifd: lan (596): udhcpc (v1.22.1) started
Mon Jan 12 20:24:27 2015 daemon.notice netifd: lan (596): Sending discover...
Mon Jan 12 20:24:27 2015 kern.info kernel: [   18.596370] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
Mon Jan 12 20:24:27 2015 kern.info kernel: [   18.613990] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
Mon Jan 12 20:24:27 2015 daemon.notice netifd: lan (596): Sending select for 192.168.0.2...
Mon Jan 12 20:24:27 2015 daemon.notice netifd: lan (596): Lease of 192.168.0.2 obtained, lease time 86400
Mon Jan 12 20:24:27 2015 kern.info kernel: [   19.109731] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Mon Jan 12 20:24:27 2015 kern.info kernel: [   19.138177] device wlan0 entered promiscuous mode
Mon Jan 12 20:24:27 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'lan' is now up
Mon Jan 12 20:24:27 2015 user.notice firewall: Reloading firewall due to ifup of lan (br-lan)
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[572]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: started, version 2.71 cachesize 150
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP no-DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack no-ipset no-auth no-DNSSEC
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: using local addresses only for domain lan
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: reading /tmp/resolv.conf.auto
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: using local addresses only for domain lan
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: read /etc/hosts - 1 addresses
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: read /tmp/hosts/dhcp - 1 addresses
Mon Jan 12 20:24:28 2015 kern.info kernel: [   20.127335] br-lan: port 1(eth0) entered forwarding state
Mon Jan 12 20:24:37 2015 kern.info kernel: [   28.573163] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
Mon Jan 12 20:24:37 2015 kern.info kernel: [   28.583842] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
Mon Jan 12 20:24:37 2015 kern.info kernel: [   28.594422] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Mon Jan 12 20:24:37 2015 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'wlan0' link is up
Mon Jan 12 20:24:37 2015 daemon.notice netifd: lan (596): Performing a DHCP renew
Mon Jan 12 20:24:37 2015 daemon.notice netifd: lan (596): Sending renew...
Mon Jan 12 20:24:37 2015 daemon.notice netifd: lan (596): Lease of 192.168.0.2 obtained, lease time 86400
Mon Jan 12 20:24:39 2015 kern.info kernel: [   30.577330] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
Mon Jan 12 20:25:21 2015 authpriv.info dropbear[740]: Child connection from 192.168.0.212:55899
Mon Jan 12 20:25:55 2015 authpriv.notice dropbear[740]: Password auth succeeded for 'root' from 192.168.0.212:55899
Mon Jan 12 20:26:29 2015 daemon.warn odhcpd[390]: DHCPV6 SOLICIT IA_NA from 000300016c709fd34a7d on br-lan: no addresses available 
Mon Jan 12 20:26:29 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: read /etc/hosts - 1 addresses
Mon Jan 12 20:26:29 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: read /tmp/hosts/odhcpd - 0 addresses
Mon Jan 12 20:26:29 2015 daemon.info dnsmasq[664]: read /tmp/hosts/dhcp - 1 addresses
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here. OpenWRT on RPi.
Ralink 5370, rt2800usb loaded, wlan0 present and even visible in Luci. No SSID broadcasted though. No obvious errors in the logs either.
Tried firmware versions 22, 24 and 29. Same result.

Log fragment:

Wed Jan 14 19:50:48 2015 user.info syslog: Usage:
    modprobe module
Wed Jan 14 19:50:48 2015 kern.info kernel: [   18.627462] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
Wed Jan 14 19:50:48 2015 kern.info kernel: [   18.645683] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.24

Seems that modprobe tries to load some module and is unable to do it.

lsmod gives this output (limited to modules mentioning rt2800).

compat                  1919  3 rt2800usb

crc_ccitt                987  1 rt2800lib

mac80211              353345  3 rt2800lib

rt2800lib              90807  1 rt2800usb

rt2800usb              14727  0

rt2x00lib              31286  3 rt2800usb

rt2x00usb               7437  1 rt2800usb

Seems like a bug or (I hope) like the OP said - something silly we're both missing.

Thanks
Smirk

EDIT:
No point in searching for a solution apparently. The only one is to recompile.
See here: https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/17679#comment:11

Comment: All right, good to know. I went back to Raspian and got a acceptable resolution there, so might stick with that for the moment.